# LoadingElementDuration doesn't fully animate

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

When using

```
AjaxOptions ajaxOpts = new AjaxOptions
{
    UpdateTargetId = "Entry",
    LoadingElementDuration = 5000,
    LoadingElementId = "Remove"
};
```

With

```
<div id="Remove">
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Data", ajaxOpts))
{
}
</div>
<div id="Entry"></div>
```

The animation call on the div "Remove" takes around 60ms, not 5000ms. Is this because it only animates during the request and disregards the actual loadingelementduration? Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The duration of the element loading will occur over the amount of loading time, so if the loading time is faster than the animation speed it goes very quickly.